# java pattern for a url

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, matcher

I want to read from a file each line and edit only the lines that presents a url from a specific server... My code is like...

```
   Scanner ReadIsbn = new Scanner (new FileReader ("C:/Users/...."));        

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("http:////www.librarything.com//isbn//");

    while ( ReadIsbn.hasNextLine()){

        String line = ReadIsbn.nextLine();
        Matcher m = pat.matcher(line);
        if (m.matches() == true) {
            EDIT line....

        }

    }

}
```

And it is not working... In fact m.matches() is always false.. 
In the file i give as input, there are lines like:

```
1)   http://www.librarything.com/isbn/0-9616696-7-5.html
2)   http://www.librarything.com/isbn/0-86078-322-7.html
Cultural tourism : how the arts can help market tourism products, how 
blablabla
```

(i want to edit only the first two lines of the example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not escape forward slashes in your pattern. This should do

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("http://www.librarything.com/isbn/");
```

Another problem is that `matches` method tries to match pattern against entire input text. Use

```
 if (m.find()){
        EDIT line....
 }
```

If you just want to check the prefix as you are doing here, then you can also use [String#startsWith](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) method

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because method `matches()` matches *full* line. You should either add `.*` to the end of your pattern

`Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("http://www.librarything.com//isbn/.*");`

or use method 'find()' instead.

Also you should not write duplicate forward slashes. This character '/' is forward, not back slash.